# With minimal changes to the object structure, how can you reference a function from another function in the same object?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Using Javascript (ES6), I need to reference an handler function `onKeyup` so that I can add and remove an event listener in two functions declared *in the same object*.

Would you see how I can access that `onKeyup` function from the two `bind` and `unbind` functions in the object? :

```js
export default {
    bind(el) {
        let privateVar = 42;

        function foobar() {
            console.log('Foobar hit', privateVar);
        }

        function onKeyup() {
            console.log('onKeyup hit');
            foobar();
        }

        el.addEventListener("keyup", onKeyup, false);
    },

    unbind(el) {
        //`onKeyup` does not exist here, how can I fix that?
        el.removeEventListener("keyup", onKeyup, false);
    }
}
```

Is this possible?

My first thought would be to modify the code like that, but the result is in my opinion less readable :

```js
export default {
    privateVar : null,

    onKeyup() {
        console.log('onKeyup hit');
        this.foobar();
    },

    foobar() {
        console.log('Foobar hit', this.privateVar);
    },

    bind(el) {
        this.privateVar = 42;
        el.addEventListener("keyup", this.onKeyup, false);
    },

    unbind(el) {
        el.removeEventListener("keyup", this.onKeyup, false);
    }
}
```

Would you have a better, cleaner way to do that?

Note : I cannot change the structure of the `bind` and `unbind` functions in that object since it is used as a [directive declaration](https://vuejs.org/guide/custom-directive.html) for Vue.js 2.*.

**EDIT:**

I also tried a second way of organizing my code :

```js
export default {
    onKeyup : null,

    bind(el) {
        let privateVar = 42;

        function foobar() {
            console.log('Foobar hit', privateVar);
        }

        this.onKeyup = function() {
            console.log('onKeyup hit');
            foobar();
        };

        el.addEventListener("keyup", this.onKeyup, false);
    },

    unbind(el) {
        el.removeEventListener("keyup", this.onKeyup, false);
    }
}
```

...but then I see this error message : `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'onKeyup' of undefined`

Comment: What is your desire?  Is your issue that you want your exports to only contain `bind()` and `unbind()` (with everything else private)?

Comment: @Makyen Ideally yes, I'd like the export to stay as close to the default vue.js directive structures, which means `bind()`, `unbind()` (as well as the default `inserted()`, `update()` and `componentUpdated()` functions). My event handlers can get quite big and each of them can call many functions, therefore I'd like to keep the logic inside each 'official' vue.js functions, as much as possible. My last edit would I guess be acceptable since I'd only declare handlers that way, not internal functions like `foobar()`.

Comment: You might want to change the title and some of the text in the question. Even from the start the title did not really reflect what you were asking.  You had already determined how to reference a function declared as a property within the same object (i.e. `this.functionName`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use an IIFE to encapsulate everything and only expose the `bind()` and `unbind()` functions.

```
export default (function() {
    var privateVar;

    function onKeyup() {
        console.log('onKeyup hit');
        foobar();
    }

    function foobar() {
        console.log('Foobar hit', privateVar);
    }

    function _bind(el) {
        privateVar = 42;
        el.addEventListener("keyup", onKeyup, false);
    }

    function _unbind(el) {
        el.removeEventListener("keyup", onKeyup, false);
    }

    return {
        bind:_bind,
        unbind:_unbind
    };
})();
```

Comment: Thank you for that answer. I managed to keep the changes too a minimum by only adding the IIFE, declaring `let onKeyup, onPaste;` at the start of the function and then doing `onKeyup = function(e) {}` in the `bind()` function.

Comment: I'm glad I was able to help.  Yeah, there are lots of ways to organize it, depending on what you want. I decided to keep it simple in order to illustrate just the IIFE.